# Resolution by container name

Tags: docker

I have two containers connected to the default `bridge` network:

```
» docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS                                                                  NAMES
3cc528ddbe7e        gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest   "/usr/bin/dumb-ini..."   25 minutes ago      Up 25 minutes                                                                                       gitlab-runner
3c01073065c7        gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest       "/assets/wrapper"        About an hour ago   Up About an hour (healthy)   0.0.0.0:45022->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:45080->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:45443->443/tcp   gitlab
```

I have found the corresponsing IP addresses with `docker inspect` (any better method of obtaining them?), and I can ping from one container to the other, by IP address:

```
» docker exec -it gitlab-runner bash
root@3cc528ddbe7e:/# ping 172.17.0.3
PING 172.17.0.3 (172.17.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.079 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.063 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.3: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.060 ms
^C
--- 172.17.0.3 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.060/0.067/0.079/0.010 ms
```

But I cannot ping by name:

```
root@3cc528ddbe7e:/# ping gitlab    
ping: unknown host gitlab
```

Why is this? I thought docker provides DNS by container name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I have two containers connected to the default `bridge` network...*
*I can ping from one container to the other, by IP address...*
*But I cannot ping by name...*

---

This is the default behavior for the default `bridge` network.

From: [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge)

> ### Differences between user-defined bridges and the default bridge
>
> - User-defined bridges provide automatic DNS resolution between containers.
>
> Containers on the **default bridge network can only access each other by IP addresses**, unless you use the `--link` option, which is considered legacy. On a user-defined bridge network, containers can resolve each other by name or alias.